# JQuery Ajax loading spinner only on first request

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
            $("#spinner").css("display", "block");
        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
            $("#spinner").css("display", "none");
        });

        $("#go").click(function() {
            $("#messager").html('<img src="spinner.gif" id="spinner">');
            $.post("send.php", {
                first:  first,
                second:  second
            }, function(result) {
                $("#messager").html(result);                
            });
        });

    });
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="messager"><img src="spinner.gif" id="spinner"></div>
```

This is the response which works fine from my `send.php`:

```
echo "something";
```

All is right if the user clicks first time on `#go`. The spinner is shown first and the then "something" is shown.

But if the user clicks the second time on `#go` the spinner is not shown.

How must I change the code that the spinner every time is show if the user click on `#go` without site reload!

Comment: I have add $("#messager").html('<img src="spinner.gif" id="spinner">');

Comment: Now it runs like I want!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#messager").html(result);
```

You are replacing the entire contents of the messager with your results.  The spinner is a child of the messager.  As such, it no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
<div id="messager"></div>
<script>


$(function() {

$("#go").click(function(){
    hideSpinner();
    $.ajax({
       url : "send.php", 
       data: { first:  first,second:  second},
       beforeSend: function() {
           showSpinner();
       },
       success: function(result){
            $("#messager").html(result);             
       },
       error: function(err) {
           console.log(err);
           hideSpinner();
       }
    });
});

});

function hideSpinner() {
if($(document).find('#spinner').length > 0) {
    $(document).find('#spinner').remove();
}
}
function showSpinner() {
    $('#messager').append('<img src="spinner.gif" id="spinner">');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to enable spinner when calling the ajax request and disabled it as soon as you got the response.
Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#go").click(function(){
        $("#spinner").css("display", "block");
        $.post("send.php", {
            first:  first,
            second:  second
        }, function(result) {
             $("#spinner").css("display", "none");
            $("#messager").html(result);                
        });
    });
```

Comment: ajaxStart and ajaxComplete are already doing this.  This is not the real issue

Comment: and you'd probably want to use `.always()` rather than the success callback, otherwise if there's an error your spinner will be "stuck" on.

Comment: @Taplar Yep you are right and i read the question differently.